# testing for one item in dictionary<k,v>

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005, dictionary

I'm using VS 2005 fx2.0.

If I know my Dictionary contains only 1 item how do I get to it?

Thanks,
rod

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way (with framework 2.0) is to iterate over it with foreach.

Or make a method that do that, like:

```
public static T GetFirstElementOrDefault<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
{
  T value = default(T);
  foreach(T val in values)
  {
    value = val;
    break;
  }
  return value;
}
```

It works with all IEnumerable and in your case T is KeyValuePair

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have `using System.Linq;`. The below command will get the key value pair of the dictionary

```
var item = Dictionary<k,v>.Single();
var key = item.Key;
var value =item.Value;
```

Comment: The question is about VS2005. To use linq you'll need VS2008 with fx3.5

Answer (score 5):

[Graviton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2675962/3834) is correct but to be a bit safer (in the event that there is more than one item) you could do this:

```
yourDictionary.First();
```

And to be *even* safer you could do this (in the event that the dictionary was empty as well):

```
yourDictionary.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over all elements of Dictionary (in this case only one)

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<v, k> keyValue in dictionary)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary.SingleOrDefault();
```